# Regex for First word and last word of a string separates with

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get a regex for the following expression but can't make it:

- String have 4 words separated with dots(.).
- First word matches a given one (HELLO for example).
- Second and third words could have any character but dot itself (.).
- Last word matches a given one again(csv for example).

So:

- HELLO.something.Somethi#gElse.csv should match.
- something.HELLO.?.csv shouldn't match.
- HELLO.something...csv shouldn't match.
- HELLO.something.somethingelse.notcsv shouldn't match

I can do it with split(.) and then check for individual words, but I'm trying to get it working with Regex and Pattern class.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include some code to show what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward, as long as you understand *character classes*. A regex with square brackets `[xyz]` matches any character from the list `{x, y, z}`; a regex `[^xyz]` matches any character *except* `{x, y, z}`.

Now you can construct your expression:

```
^HELLO\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.csv$
```

`+` means "one or more of the preceding expression"; `\.` means "dot itself". `^` means "the beginning of the string"; `$` means "the end of the string". These anchors prevent regex from matching

```
blahblahHELLO.world.world.csvblahblah
```

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/dO9vT3/1)

A common goal for writing regular expressions like that is to *capture* some content, for example, the string between the first and the second dot, and the string between the second and the third dot. Use *capturing groups* to bring the content of these strings into your Java program:

```
^HELLO\.([^.]+)\.([^.]+)\.csv$
```

Each pair of parentheses defines a capturing group, indexed from `1` (group at index zero represents the capture of the entire expression). Once you obtain a match object from the pattern, you can query it for the groups, and extract the corresponding strings.

Note that backslashes in Java regex need to be doubled.

Comment: If `HELLO...csv` is a valid match then switch from `+` - *one or more* to `*` - *zero or more*.

Comment: Nice answer. You might want to demonstrate a regex where the first word can be HELLO or WORLD or FOO, and the last word can be csv or xls or txt

Comment: Could also mention using groups to collect each word from the match.

Comment: Thank you very much, really helped me understanding Regex a bit better too :)

Comment: also consider wrapping the words you need to match (`HELLO` and `csv`) in [Pattern.quote](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote-java.lang.String-) method. (if you're getting them from some variable)

Answer (score 0):

```
(^HELLO\.[^.]+\.[^.]+\.csv$)
```

[Here is the same regex with token explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lC0nR6/1).